# Can I post a picture as whatsapp status , messenger or instagram story by clicking button from my app in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, whatsapp

want to develop an application which will have some custom images and user can send it to anyone's inbox on messenger and instagram etc. Additionally i want to post whatsapp whatsapp status or instagram , messenger story from my application 
is it possible is yes recommend me some articles or tutorial thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No you cant post the status or story from your app. For messenger story you need to check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios

Answer (score 0):

you can't update whatsapp status from your app